# How to do a special order clause in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a result set like this: a b c

This result will be fixed each time. What I need to do is order the rows like this a c b. 
How can I do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql Custom Order for fixed values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843366/postgresql-custom-order-for-fixed-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  value
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        CASE value WHEN 'a' THEN 1 WHEN 'c' THEN 2 WHEN 'b' THEN 3 END
```

Comment: Or... `order by some_immutable_function(value)`