# Postgresql Custom Order for fixed values

Tags: postgresql

I need a select result to look like this

```
UK
Europe
USA
```

The values are fixed ( no table is need it ). The order is important so ORDER BY 1 is not working.

What is the sql query ( as simple as possible ) that will build this result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [VALUES lists](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-values.html):

```sql
VALUES ('UK'), ('Europe'), ('USA');
 column1
---------
 UK
 Europe
 USA
(3 rows)
```